# How to set class using execCommand?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello I have the following to set a link:

```
function iLink() {
  var linkURL = prompt("Enter the URL for this link:", "http://");
  richTextField.document.execCommand("CreateLink", false, linkURL);
```

This works but i want to change the class of the link, so i tried:

```
var linkURL = prompt("Enter the URL for this link:", "http://");
richTextField.document.execCommand("CreateLink", false, linkURL);
var listId = window.getSelection().focusNode.parentNode;
$(listId).addClass("alink");
```

But that didnt work, have I done something wrong with the above code or is their another way i can implement a class name?

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't have jquery loaded on the page, and you don't need jquery anyway.

Try:

```
richTextField.getSelection().focusNode.parentNode.classList.add("alink");
```